# UITableView Text not Updating from Computed Property

Tags: swift, uitableview, computed-properties

I'm trying to update a tableViewCell label's text with a computed property.  When I create the cell the label updates appropriately, however when I attempt to update it from a delegate it doesn't change.  What strange is that a print statement immediately proceeding it (and within the cellForRowAt) updates correctly.

```
var globalTime : String = "12:00 PM"

struct Task {

  var taskType: String
  var taskInstructions: String
  var taskDurationTime: Int
  var taskStartTime: String {
    return calculateTimeInternal(from: globalTime, taskDuration: taskDurationTime)!
    }

  func calculateTimeInternal(from endTime: String, taskDuration: Int) -> String? {
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
     let calendar = Calendar.current

     let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, minute: -taskDuration)
     if let time = dateFormatter.date(from: endTime),
         let startTime = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: time, wrappingComponents: false) {
         return dateFormatter.string(from: startTime)
     }
     return nil
  }

}

extension ViewController : TimeChangedDelegate {

  func timerChanged(time: String) {

    globalTime = time
    myTableView.reloadData()

  }
}

//Inside myTableView cellForRowAt...


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)
        as! myTableViewCell

        print("taskStartTime is \(meal.arrayOfTasks[indexPath.row].taskStartTime)") //Updates correctly
        cell.planTime.text = "\(meal.arrayOfTasks[indexPath.row].taskStartTime)" //Updates wrong

        cell.planLabel.text = "\(meal.arrayOfTasks[indexPath.row].taskStartTime)"

        return UITableViewCell()
}
```

The print statement updates accurately, however the cell.planTime.text doesn't change.  Why would they be different?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling the update from a background thread?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of.

Comment: In `timerChanged()` try calling `reloadData` on the main queue: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.myTableView.reloadData() }`.

Comment: Good thought; doesn't seem to help though.

Comment: add more code like, cellForRow method code and UITableVIewCell Class code.

Comment: Updated; though unfortunately that's not much but hopefully helpful.

Comment: @moosgrn, you are returning **UITableViewCell** instead of ***cell (myTableViewCell)***. how could your text would change if you return UITableViewCell() instance rather **myTableViewCell** which is your Custom Cell?

Comment: @ImrulKayes tried that; issue still remains.

Comment: @ImrulKayes looks like you had the right idea; I just needed to change my return to "cell".  Thanks!

Comment: @moosgrn your code clearly showed where was the problem. glad you figured that out.

Comment: taskStartTime is a String, it does not need to be wrapped in "\()". You can simply write: cell.planLabel.text = meal.arrayOfTasks[indexPath.row].taskStartTime